# What are subjects that could be taught on calculus 1 but often are not?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

On the top of my head I have some examples:

- sometimes people don't learn solving harder limits using Taylor series
- people may not learn sinh and cosh functions and its properties
- sometimes Euler's substitutions for integrands is not taught

What are some other topics that could be taught on a calculus 1 course but are left behind?

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic for this site, but personally I'd probably cut down a bit on algebraic methods for integration.  That stuff is much better handled by machines these days.  I would, somewhat paradoxically, increase attention on numerical methods.  Those ideas drive a whole lot.

Comment: Computer algebra systems *love* to use $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ instead of linear combinations of $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$, which seems odd considering how rarely $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ are taught in school.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @lulu to my mind, the main pedagogic point of "doing" algebraic methods is that for someone inclined to enjoy calculus (1 and 2) at all, algebraic manipulation is principally what can/will be enjoyed. In all fairness, I don't think one can say that about numerical methods... On the downside, sigh, along with high school algebra, enjoying that kind of thing tricked me into believing that I was good at math.

Comment: The "main" in "The main pedagogic point " in my previous is hyperbolic... How about "a point in favor of".

Comment: @peterag  Understood!  But...well, I have to integrate things all the time for finance.  There are no closed form solutions, ever.  I don't even try for those.  And naive numerical methods are ineffective as well.  You need numerical methods adapted to the problem you are working on.  That's my point.

Answer (score 2):

Quadratic approximation and Newton's method give students a chance to practice plugging into formulas with derivatives in them such as: $$\frac{f''(a)}{2} (x-a)^2 + f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)$$
So that if they encounter a formula with derivatives later on they know what to do.

Also, a key concept in calculus is error arithmetic/sensitivity. It's helpful to look at limits and derivatives in terms of "if we know the input to a function is roughly $x$ with this level of uncertainty, the output is roughly $y$ with this level of uncertainty". This is essential for engineering, but I hardly see this covered in Calc 1 textbooks.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from those mentioned, I would definitely include:

1. Successive differences (forward, centered, etc) and Newton's interpolation formula, probably the best way to derive Taylor's formula;
2. Geometric objects like the osculating circle, the radius of curvature, etc.
3. Reasoning with infinitesimals. You can prove formulas for derivatives in two lines with a picture. Plus if you read Physics or Engineering books, they are everywhere, especially in Thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

**Topics which are often or occasionally left out of Calculus courses**

Epsilon delta proofs applying formal definition of a limit.
See [Epsilon delta example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467948/epsilon-delta-proof)  Also, I've seen course totally gloss over the formal definition of a limit except for listing it in the textbook.

Sometimes or even often the formal summation methods and Riemann sums are left out.  Of course this makes it harder to grasp series in Calculus II.

I don't see Simpson's method taught much, usually just summation by right hand endpoint, left hand endpoint or midpoint.

Of course Business Calculus, Calculus for Biology, or Calculus for the Social Sciences frequently leave out half or more of a traditional Calculus course for math majors or engineers.

Of course if the Calculus sequence is split over four courses at 3 credit hours each instead of the usual four or five hour credit sequence spread over 3 courses the topic breakdown by course will vary significantly.